# Appending to tbody not showing data in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I am trying to append some data to a Datatables tbody. I do recieve the data when I console.log() the data, but the data does not show when I try to append it to my Datatable (The id of my table is 'example' btw). I do not know where to go in terms of debugging this as well.

```
    asyncRequest.then((tracks) => {
      var tableData = '';
      // rows
      for (track in tracks) {
        tableData += '<tr>';
        tableData += '<td>' + tracks[track]._id + '</td>';
        tableData += '<td>' + tracks[track].Position + '</td>';
        tableData += '<td>' + tracks[track].Track + '</td>';
        tableData += '<td>' + tracks[track].Artist + '</td>';
        tableData += '<td>' + tracks[track].Streams + '</td>';
        tableData += '<td>' + tracks[track].Url + '</td>';
        tableData += '<td>' + tracks[track].Date + '</td>';
        tableData += '</tr>';
      }
      console.log(tableData);

      $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#example').DataTable();
        $(table).find('tbody').append(tableData);
      });
    });
  </script>
```

tracks: `[0 … 99]
0:
_id: "5e8d677a6e5216bc865e084a"
Position: 1
Track: "Dance Monkey"
Artist: "Tones And I"
Streams: 6155025
Url: "https://open.spotify.com/track/1rgnBhdG2JDFTbYkYRZAku"
Date: "1/1/20"`

Comment: u should rerender table.

Comment: This isn't how DataTables is generally used. It typically receives a JSON object containing the data to be displayed. Take a look at the various [data source](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/index.html) approaches.

Comment: @andrewjames the data in their dataSet is an array of arrays... my dataset is a JSON object (array of objects), so when I try that approach I get an alert ```DataTables warning: table id=example - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4```

Comment: True, but that is just one possible structure. Could you edit your question to show a representative sample of your data?

Comment: OK - Thank you for showing some data. I was hoping to see a sample of the actual JSON. I see you have accepted an answer, and I am glad you have a solution that meets your needs. But be aware it's typically not a good idea to [destroy the DataTable object](https://datatables.net/reference/option/destroy), if you are only trying to load data (it is unnecessarily inefficient). You can certainly do it - but you are fighting against DataTables, by doing things that way.

Comment: @andrewjames would the proper way be to convert each object to an array then pass the entire array?

Comment: To help answer that question, I would really need to see the JSON - or a representative sample.

Comment: Take a look at [these examples](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/). One of these should probably match the structure of your JSON. The first 4 in the list are the most common.

Comment: Thank you @andrewjames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can u try this one fisrt destroy then  append then refresh it

and put your document ready out of request and initialize there

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#example').DataTable();

      });
```

then after u take data appen it destroy it and refresh it

```
asyncRequest.then((tracks) => {
      var tableData = '';
      // rows
      for (track in tracks) {
        tableData += '<tr>';
        tableData += '<td>' + tracks[track]._id + '</td>';
        tableData += '<td>' + tracks[track].Position + '</td>';
        tableData += '<td>' + tracks[track].Track + '</td>';
        tableData += '<td>' + tracks[track].Artist + '</td>';
        tableData += '<td>' + tracks[track].Streams + '</td>';
        tableData += '<td>' + tracks[track].Url + '</td>';
        tableData += '<td>' + tracks[track].Date + '</td>';
        tableData += '</tr>';
      }
      console.log(tableData);


      $('#example').DataTable().destroy();
      $('#example').find('tbody').append(str);
      $('#example').DataTable().draw();
    });
```

Comment: ```TypeError: table.fnDestroy is not a function```

Comment: which libraries do u use https://jsfiddle.net/5twrcqmx/1 I added on example here. Can u change your libraries with in example and try again

Comment: Thank you @Çağrı

Comment: For future reference, instead of manipulating content in this way, it would be better to use the features built in to DataTables for handling JSON. For example, see [here](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/). Destroying the DataTable object because of content changes is not typically the best approach. It certainly works, but there is probably a better way.